# All images show on load with JQuery Cycle 2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-cycle

I am using the JQuery Cycle 2 plugin with some images and the `fadeout` effect. Eg:

```
$('#imageticker').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fadeout', 
    delay:  -2000 
});
```

and:

```
<ul id="imageticker">
  <li><img src="image1.png"/></li>
  <li><img src="image2.png"/></li>
  <li><img src="image3.png"/></li>
</ul>
```

This works, but when the page loads I can see all the images stacked up on each other. It is only after the first transition that hidden images disappear and it works as it should. Would anyone know how to amend this?

Comment: create a demo so we can see your css. Doesn't take much css to contain the images using overflow and some dimensioning. Also always a good practice to set width/height on image tags

Comment: It works fine here. check this : http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/vJ4pX/

Comment: I gave you the clues... simple css will handle the problem. Inspect the css applied by plugin in console and copy some of that to your css stylesheet

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a go - transferring all of the inline css the plugin created to my stylesheet - but it makes no difference

Comment: what browser(s)? Page opened fine for me...so hard to see what you see

Comment: @charlietfl I've tried Chrome and FireFox. Weird thing is it works fine with other transitions like scrollHorz

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding issue... is it `FOUC ( Flash Of Unstyled Content)` prior to javascript kicking in? That's what I'm assuming which is what css should fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got it. It seems the `fade` is the default option and adding it to the plugin script caused this.

So, I changed

```
$('#imageticker').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade', 
    delay:  -2000 
});
```

To just:

```
$('#imageticker').cycle({ 
    delay:  -2000 
});
```

and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have transparent images, it may be better to use the **`fade`** effect instead of `fadeout`. After each transition:

- with `fadeout`, only one image has `opacity: 0`, the others are set to `1`;
- with `fade`, only one image has `opacity: 1`, the others are set to `0`.

(I also tried to play with the initial opacity, but it didn't help.)